# How to display scrollbar in only one iframe while making other frames fixed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an initial page with something like this:

```
<body>
<iframe src = "page1.html" style="position:fixed; width:100%; height:100px; left:0; top:0 overflow:hidden"</iframe> 
<iframe src = "page2.html" style="position:fixed; width:100px; height:100%; left:0; top:100px; overflow:hidden"></iframe> 
<iframe src = "page3.html" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; left:100px; top:100px; overflow:scroll"></iframe> 
</body>
```

Basically, page1 is the title, page2 is the menu on the left and page3 is the content.

I would like to make page1 and page2 fixed without any scrollbars but only have scrollbars on page3.html. The above code displays two scrollbars, one for the whole body and another for page3.html
I do not want 2 scrollbars but only one, and when I add

```
<body style="overflow:hidden">,
```

the scrollbar for page 3 is also hidden. I tried using (overflow:scroll !important) but did not work. Is there any way to do this elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the width of page3 too high, 100% will push the edge of the iframe, scrollbar included, beyond the edge of the body whose over flow is hidden

```
<body style="overflow:hidden">  
<iframe src = "http://www.amazon.com" style="position:fixed; width:100%; height:100px;     left:0; top:0; overflow:hidden"></iframe> 
<iframe src = "http://www.amazon.com" style="position:fixed; width:100px; height:100%; left:0; top:100px; overflow:hidden"></iframe> 
<iframe src = "http://www.amazon.com" style="position:absolute; width:50%; height:100%; left:100px; top:100px; overflow:scroll;"></iframe> 
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VBZKa/1/

you may need to calculate width with javascript

Comment: I used javascript to calculate the viewing area of the screen and change the width and height of page3 accordingly. It worked. Thanks very much.